# Reordering Index to a specific order

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, reindex

I have a dataframe called exam and I would like to sort the month column (which is the index) according to the common order (Jan, feb, mar, apr, etc). However, it seems to be sorted in ascending order. I tried the reindex command but it didn't make a difference. How can I order it as I want?

Here is the code

```
exam.reindex(['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November'])
```

Here is the dataframe
[image]

Comment: kindly provide sample dataframe, with expected output

Comment: Please paste your dataframe as text, not an image

Comment: Did you assign the result of `exam.reindex()` to the new dataframe? Your code suggests you didn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to assign it back

```
exam = exam.reindex(['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November'])
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
new_index = ['January','February','March','April','May','June','July','August','September','October','November']
exam = exam.loc[new_index]
```